# Html page on reload different html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First time html loads and it display text as Yes and second time when reloads or loads from cache it should display some other text NO.

Comment: Okay, you need to ask a specific question, that way we know what we're answering (and what you expect). Also, it helps if you can show that you've tried something already, are you having a particular problem implementing this?

Comment: @karpra-Can you please clarify the question here? I assume you mean: "_Is there a way that I can display 'Yes' in text the first time a page loads, but then displays 'No' when the page loads again or loads from cache?_"

Comment: Set a cookie, try jquery cookie

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery, it seemed easiest to use the [jQuery Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

```
// assigns the value returned by the cookie to the variable,
// if no cookie, or no value, is returned, the string is assigned instead.
var cookieValue = $.cookie('firstVisit') || 'Yes';

// if there's no cookie, then a cookie is set.
if (!$.cookie('firstVisit')) {
    $.cookie('firstVisit', 'No', {
        expires: 7 // expires in 7 days, adjust to taste.
    });
}

$('#firstVisit').text(cookieValue);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uNp2E/1/).

The above code updated to be a little tidier, and less repetitive:

```
// if the cookie is not set, the cookieVal variable is falsey
var cookieVal = $.cookie('firstVisit'),
    // creating a reference to the relevant div
    div = $('#firstVisit');

// if the cookieVal evaluates to false the cookie is set,
// and the text of the div is 'Yes'
if (!cookieVal) {
    $.cookie('firstVisit', 'No');
    div.text('Yes');
}
// otherwise...
else {
    // text of the div is equal to the value returned from the cookie
    div.text(cookieVal);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uNp2E/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to recognize a returning visitor:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript">

// sets a cookie with a certain name, value and optional expiration in days
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

// retrieves the value of a cookie of a certain name (or returns undefined)
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) return unescape(y);
    }
}

// if the cookie was set, then the user has been here already
if (getCookie("visited") == "true") {
    document.write("NO");
} else {
    // otherwise, set the cookie and assume the user has not been here before
    setCookie("visited", "true");
    document.write("YES");  
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: The requirement is first time i get a html/jsp say html1 after submitting the html1 it installs a profile on iOS mobile device and after completing the installation there is a done button when you click on it, it is opening a browser with same html1 which i have visited last time this time i wanted it to redirect it to a different URL. Currently i find the same html1 page as is and i don't know how to redirect it new URL when it comes back..

Comment: Thanks for this approach but i wanted to control the code not based on cookies but on session i have a code snippet please correct if i'm wrong..  out.println( "<html>" i want to check a condition with script let tags and display the html based on the session..

Comment: here is code snippet i tried  out.println(
           "<html>"+
             "<head><title>Using Post Method in JSP Form.</title></head>"+
             "<body>"+
              "<form action=\"/mportal/enroll\" method=\"post\">"+

              <% if(session.getAttribute("test") == null) {
                   "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />"+
                "else"+
                "<a href=\"https://test.com\">Click Me</a>"+
               "} %>"+
             "</form>"+    
             "</body>"+
             "</html>");

Comment: Please correct me if i can use jsp scriptlets inside out.println